# How to aimate the before and after pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

I want to make like this shape using HTML and CSS: [image: animated image]

this is my code but why the before and after elements don't stop rotation when I hover on it:

Code:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #1790e1 #1790e1 transparent #1790e1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #fca400 #fca400 #fca400 transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

div::after:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

div::before:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

My question is how to animate and pause the rotation of two pseudo elements when I hover on it to make like the design in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your selectors from:

```
div:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

div::after:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

div::before:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

to:

```
div:hover,
div:hover::after,
div:hover::before {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

your selectors indicate an over on the pseudo-elements. since you only hover the div itself you need to add the `::before/after` selector after the `:hover` selector.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

div {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent #ea2264 #ea2264 #ea2264;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #1790e1 #1790e1 transparent #1790e1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: #fca400 #fca400 #fca400 transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

div:hover,
div:hover::after,
div:hover::before {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```